# how can I use a combo box in my form to enter different values in different fields in MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access, combobox, data-entry

I have a primary table holding default values which I want to enter as values in a form I created.  The primary table is TblDefault, the related table that the form was created with is TblAssessment.  DefID is the id common to both.  The combobox is cboDefault, and it's working by displaying the values.  But the challenge I am having is writing the vba code to be able to select a value from the combobox and enter that value in the form field.  There are 5 fields in the form, text fields "Ques1Comment", "Ques2Comment", etc. Please I need help!!!

```
Private Sub cboDefault_AfterUpdate()
Dim defaultID As Variant
defaultID = Me!\[DefID\].Value

    Dim selectedField As String
    selectedField = Me![cboDefault].Value
    
    Select Case selectedField
        Case "Ques1Comment"
            Me![Ques1Comment].Value = DLookup("DefaultValue", "TblDefault", "DefaultName = '" & defaultID & "'")
        Case "Ques2Comment"
            Me![Ques2Comment].Value = DLookup("DefaultValue", "TblDefault", "DefaultName = '" & defaultID & "'")
        ' ... Repeat for other fields
    End Select
    
    Me![cboDefault].Requery ' Requery the combo box control

End Sub
```

Comment: Why would DefaultName = defaultID?  Edit question to provide example of TblDefault data as a formatted text table. Why are there backslashes in posted code - `Me!\[DefID\].Value`?

Comment: Why is DefID in both tables? Is this a primary key/foreign key relationship? If you save DefID why do you need to save text values? This appears to be duplication of data between tables. Is user permitted to edit these 5 fields? Do you want to overwrite user inputs if combobox selection is changed?

Comment: You want same default for all 5 fields? Don't need DLookup. Include text field as column of combobox and reference that column by index in VBA - column 2 is index 1: `Me.Ques1Comment = Me.cboDefault.Column(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to do this effort

1 - as example create this table
[image: Table Design]
2 - create your form and assign this query to your combo box
[image: Form controls]
3 - Set combo box prosperities as follow
[image: combo box query]
[image: properities]
4 - Assign this code to combo box after update event

```vb
Private Sub EmpID_AfterUpdate()
    If Trim([EmpID] & "") = vbNullString Then
        Me.EmpAge = ""
        Me.EmpBDate = ""
        Me.EmpAddress = ""
    Else
        Me.EmpAge = Me.EmpID.Column(2)
        Me.EmpBDate = Me.EmpID.Column(3)
        Me.EmpAddress = Me.EmpID.Column(4)
    End If
End Sub
```

5 - Final Result as follow
[image]
6 - Download attached Sample
[Link to download sample](https://www.mediafire.com/file/q9m4lf345ycb5l7/Combobox.accdb/file)

Answer (score 0):

Your VBA code seems mostly correct, but you're using "DefaultName" in your `DLookup` queries instead of "DefID," which you mentioned is the common ID between the tables. Here's the corrected code:

```vb
Private Sub cboDefault_AfterUpdate()
    Dim defaultID As Variant
    defaultID = Me![DefID].Value
    
    Dim selectedField As String
    selectedField = Me![cboDefault].Value
    
    Select Case selectedField
        Case "Ques1Comment"
            Me![Ques1Comment].Value = DLookup("DefaultValue", "TblDefault", "DefID = " & defaultID)
        Case "Ques2Comment"
            Me![Ques2Comment].Value = DLookup("DefaultValue", "TblDefault", "DefID = " & defaultID)
        ' ... Repeat for other fields
    End Select
    
    Me![cboDefault].Requery ' Requery the combo box control
End Sub
```

Make sure the field names and table names are correct in your database schema. This code assumes that the field "DefaultValue" in "TblDefault" contains the value you want to copy to the form fields. Also, ensure that the "DefID" field in "TblDefault" is numeric, as you're using it in your `DLookup` query.