# MS Access If Statement works but throws error anyways

Tags: ms-access

I have a Combobox that is filled with 3 values (PSA, lashing, lifting) from a table. Those values are type "short Text". With that I built a macro that changes the values of labels depending on what is selected in the Combobox.

```
[Forms]![Menu]![Combo87].[Text]="PSA" THEN 

SetProperty 
Property Caption 
Value "Persons"
```

The Problem now is that on one hand the code works as expected and changes the values but on the other hand I always get a type mismatch error (13).

```
SetLocalVar
__*L0_; [Forms]![Menu]![Combo87].[Text]="PSA"
```

Can anybody help me? I tried OnError but that wont help. I also don`t understand how a type mismatch can happen when the combobox is filled with text and "PSA" is also text.

After trying to change the value for the caption from Persons to "Persons" and back to "Persons" the error code changed to 3021 but still works (except from the error popping up every click)

Comment: Don't use `.Text`, use `.Value` or don't reference any property because Value is the default for data controls.

Comment: Instead of a macro setting label Caption property, could use a textbox with an expression: `=IIf([Combo87] = "PSA", "Persons", "something else")`. Is form in Single view? Programmatically changing property of control affects ALL instances of control, so in Continuous or Datasheet view all records will show the same caption in label. Use textbox with dependent expression and each record will show appropriate result.

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between text shows in `Combobox` and the value of combo box , you can hide the value and show only text , because you can't update combo box while you are set focus on it .

[image: Combo box allow you to show text but with different value]

[Please See my answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76947533/how-can-i-use-a-combo-box-in-my-form-to-enter-different-values-in-different-fiel/76949349#76949349)

[and you can download the sample mentioned here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/q9m4lf345ycb5l7/Combobox.accdb/file)